# how to jump to the folder being viewed in any file manager instantly in file dialogue

Tags: filemanager

I found the feature to quickly open a folder that is being viewed in the file manager on Windows by using [Listary](https://www.listary.com/quick-switch).

Is there a way to have something similar to this feature in Thunar?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **:-)** As Ubuntu comes with multiple possible file managers depending on the flavour and/or Desktop Environment, there is no such thing as ***the** file manager* in Ubuntu.  *(The disadvantage of freedom and choice)* **;-)** Could you please [edit] your question and provide the name of the file manager you're using?  *Maybe* it can be done with a custom script inside your file manager.  (Generally, you can find this in `help`-`about` when opening your file manager)

Comment: Pertinent question. I hate having to browse to my current working directory again and again and again for each application during a session. Can be avoided to some extent by double-clicking an existing file in the file manager for opening. Indeed, please indicate whether you are using standard Ubuntu, or another Ubuntu version (Xubuntu, Kubuntu) because all have different file managers.

Comment: @PerlDuck I think this question is not about open in terminal. This is about "File > Save" and "File > Save As" dialog in **other** applications. OP wants the "File > Save As" window (say in LibreWriter) to open in the same location as whatever location is open in the file manager (say in Thunar).

Comment: user68186, yes, I want exactly this feature

Comment: @user68186 Then I misunderstood the question. I deleted my comment.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1097449/edit) your question and explain more clearly what you want. You can use the text in my comments and more. More people understand your question there is a better chance you will get an answer.